# How to create an if then statement to drop dates for the same observation

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have an example subset of 1 patient that where I created 2 separate dates. That is "Date" and "Pending_Date".  I also created a variable where each row is either `Pending='YES'` or `Pending='NO'`. Below is my table of what I have and what I want. How can I code if Date is less than Pending_Date then exclude='yes' then I would drop my exclusions.

I tried it using an if then statement, but it will only compare dates right next to each other (ex 3/29/2023 > blank date) but I want it to take into consideration the other dates as well. For example, Obs 3 is a pending date and not greater Obs 1,2 4,5, and 8 so that won't get excluded. However, Obs 6 is a pending date and is greater than Obs 1,2, and 4 which is how I have my "Want" table.

Again I want my exclusion to be " Pending_Date > Date then Exclude='YES' " but I want all the "Dates" to be taken into consideration.

What's the best way to approach this?

[image: HAVE]

[image: WANT]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input Patient_ID $ Pending $ (Pending_Date Date)(:mmddyy10.);
format Pending_Date Date mmddyy10.;
infile datalines dlm = ',' missover;
datalines;        
AB1,NO ,          ,03/29/2022 
AB1,NO ,          ,03/29/2022 
AB1,YES,03/29/2022,           
AB1,NO ,          ,03/29/2022 
AB1,NO ,          ,04/05/2022 
AB1,YES,04/05/2022,           
AB1,YES,04/05/2022,           
AB1,NO ,          ,04/05/2022 
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select *
   from have a
   where Pending = 'YES' or Date >= 
     (select max(Pending_Date) 
      from have b
      where a.Patient_ID = b.Patient_ID)
   ;
quit;
```

Result:

```
Patient_ID Pending Pending_Date Date
AB1        YES     03/29/2022   .
AB1        NO      .            04/05/2022
AB1        YES     04/05/2022   .
AB1        YES     04/05/2022   .
AB1        NO      .            04/05/2022
```